# How can I reduce loss with my keras TensorFlow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I have a dataset of about 140,000 samples with 5 inputs, the velocity of the car, the acceleration of the car, the velocity of the lead car gathered with radar, the distance of the lead car, and the acceleration of the lead car. The output is from 0 to 1, 0 being maximum brake, and 1 being max acceleration.

I'm a beginner to neural nets, so I'm having trouble optimizing my model to get the best accuracy/loss for this data. I've been experimenting with changing the optimizer, activation function, number of hidden layers, number of nodes in the layers, etc but nothing seems to be lowering the loss over time.

Here's my current model:

```
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, activation="tanh", input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:])))
for i in range(40):
    model.add(Dense(60, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

I'm not too worried about overfitting my data right now as I can work on that later, I'm just trying to basically memorize the data to see how low I can get the loss, just to see if I can improve it. And predict on data that was trained to make sure it can return the correct output. However the lowest I've gotten the validation loss is around `0.015`, which definitely isn't returning the current output in my tests, it's about 90% accurate.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Should I be increasing my model size, or decreasing it? Nothing I've tried seems to be working. I've also made sure to normalize my 5 inputs and 1 output independently. It seems it never learns anything after a few epochs.

Thanks if anyone decides to help me on this very specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to help but there's not too much info there.

First what's the aim of the network? It's hard to tell what you're trying to reduce the loss **of**. What's your loss function? What are your labels? This seems like a classic reinforcement learning question, rather than a traditional supervised learning problem. How's the data structured? I'm assuming they're "runs" with some sort of score?

A blanket thing, that's probably too many layers.

Most of the time with networks the biggest improvement comes with cleaning your data (which we'll assume is fine) and messing with your loss function. It's best to start with a simple model and figure out if you need more.

There's also this, which is reinforcement learning, but it's a good example https://github.com/lexfridman/deeptraffic

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to predict whether the car should apply gas or brakes, or coast based on the lead vehicle and its data. The loss function is the standard function with keras, mean squared error I believe. I'll try and reduce the number of layers and up the node number

Comment: Good luck :) I can have another look in the morning. I'd consider looking at reinforcement learning. Given you probably want a score per action.

Comment: I didn't realize an activation function on the output layer was recommended, tried that and getting about half the loss! Still not super great at retaining all the data it was trained on and returning though. Have about 20 layers with 40 nodes each now. Is that still too high? There are 100,000 samples

Comment: It's hard to know without knowing a lot more about what you're trying to do, like I mentioned above. I'm still not quite sure what you're trying to minimise, I'm assuming you're doing new "runs" and trying to get the car to drive itself in an optimal way?

Comment: Yeah, I gathered data for about an hour at highway speeds and when trying the model I trained at .015 loss, it performed very poorly and just didn't seem to learn a lot. I'm thinking this could be lack of data, so I'm enlisting the help of a few friends to gather more data and I'll retrain it and see what happens.